# Problem getting the current time in seconds in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I need to retrieve the current time in seconds in a old machine (bash version 4.3) and this command is not working.

```
date +%s
```

It retrieves "%s" Any idea of what is wrong here?

Comment: No idea, but add the output of the following commands to the question: `which date`; `date --version`; `date '+%s'`; `/usr/bin/date '+%s'`. That will help finding the problem.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to bash. However, it can depend on the version of `date` you are using. (1) What OS are you running, and (2) which _date_ do you have (`date --version`)? (3) Could it be that you have more than one `date` in your PATH? What does `type -a date` reveal?

Answer (score 1):

```
nawk 'BEGIN {srand();time=srand();print time}' </dev/null
```

Comment: A slightly more portable way: `PATH=$(getconf PATH) awk 'BEGIN{srand();print srand()}'` - This is to make sure that the Posix version of `awk` is used that guarantees that behavior of `srand`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `printf` function.

```
$ printf '%(%s)T' -1

1635846449
```